# How to get changes on SharePoint site using webhook?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, postman, webhooks

I working on SharePoint webhook notifications using [Get started with SharePoint webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks). I have used below given request for subscription.

**Post request:**

```
https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/lists('<List-ID>')/subscriptions
```

As I added a word file in my SharePoint site the breakpoint got hit and gave me the following output:

```
'Resource: c3442089-2a67-4e55-94c9-b6770892299b'
'SubscriptionId: 32b45ad9-4d20-4a17-bfa3-2958cb38ead8'
'TenantId: 7a17cb7d-6898-423f-8839-45f363176f07'
'SiteUrl: /'
'WebId: 62b80f0b-f889-4974-a519-cc148413be40'
'ExpirationDateTime: 2016-10-27T16:17:57.0000000Z'
```

Now, I want check which modification has done on SharePoint site using above output for which I have got [List resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531433(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#list-resource) link. How can I use this code to get changes on my SharePoint site?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer? If there is anything unclear, you can post it at comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the official dcumentation: [SharePoint webhooks sample reference implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/webhooks-reference-implementation)

There is a video tutorial which can guide you in details. And you may get the code sample for managing changes: [ChangeManager.cs](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-samples/blob/master/Samples/WebHooks.List/SharePoint.WebHooks.Common/ChangeManager.cs)

Good luck!